# How to enforce useCallback?

Tags: reactjs

As library authors, how do you enforce useCallback usages for your library?

For example, I have created a library component which receives a callback function:

```
const myHandler = () => {
  // do something
};

return (<LibraryComponent onHandler={myHandler} />);
```

Now I would want to have developers who use this LibraryComponent to use useCallback:

```
const myHandler = React.useCallback(() => {
  // do something
}, []);

return (<LibraryComponent onHandler={myHandler} />);
```

Is there any way I can enforce this if I have only control over the LibraryComponent as library author?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: If you could be sure dependencies are always `[]` then you could store it with `useRef()` by yourself but you can't be sure about that. You could use `useMemo()` using `[onHandler.toString()]` as dependency but again converting a closure to string will lose its context. TLDR: no, it's caller responsibility because you don't know how your component will be used. Your component has the responsibility to work as intended regardless how its inputs are provided. If you are trying to enforce a coding guideline for your team then you'd better add a **linter rule** for this.